# Android Studio Test are included in signed apk?

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, android-drawable

I have a **Android Studio** project with some test. The test have his own **res/drawable** folder with some images that are needed to run the test. My question is...

Those images are included when I make the apk or will be omitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default they will be omitted as long as you put the resources in the correct folders, that is "src/test/res/drawable".

Remember that it's possible to customize source/test paths and even have more than one path for each of these, so beware of customizations in your build.gradle files!

Comment: Then I'll put in the testAndroid/res/drawable folder. I'll look the build.gradle options too. Thank you !

Comment: Do you have a source for this?